# SQL: declaring a specific field at once

Tags: sql

I am stuck in a SQL problem. I need to create a table to fill out all the requirements:
- Only users from the users table can exist within users_roles.
- Only roles from the roles table can exist within users_roles.
- A user can only have a specific role once.

```
TABLE users
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
userName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL

TABLE roles
id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
role VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
```

My Code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles (
  userId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  roleId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(userId) REFERENCES users(id),
  FOREIGN KEY(roleId) REFERENCES roles(id)
)
```

And, the problem is I am missing the requirement "- A user can only have a specific role once." Someone has any idea how to declare it?

The statements below should pass.

```
INSERT INTO users_roles(userId, roleId) VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO users_roles(userId, roleId) VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO users_roles(userId, roleId) VALUES(2, 2);
```

The statement below should fail.

```
INSERT INTO users_roles(userId, roleId) VALUES(2, NULL);
```

Comment: "A user can only have a specific role once." and " user will have always a role linked it" are not the same thing. If the former is the actual requirement then a unique constraint on `userId, roleId` should suffice. The last statement in your example should already fail due to the `NOT NULL` constraint on `roleId`

Comment: The _combination_ of `userId` and `roleId` needs to be unique, not just `roleId`.

Comment: shouldn't you just make userID unique, in addition to the foreign keys?

Comment: "The combination of userId and roleId needs to be unique, not just roleId." Both alternatives were used, and the last requirement pass, but another test fails returning only the values: 
Hints
Output
Tests: 3 pass / 1 fail
userId    roleId     
---------------- 
1         1          
2         2

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 2):

Your last condition is simply a unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE users_roles (
  userId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  roleId INTEGER NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (roleId) REFERENCES roles (id),
  UNIQUE (userId, roleId)
);
```

Comment: Perfect! I was including the "UNIQUE" as part of userId and roleId declaration. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the table schema:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`userId`, `roleId`)
```